# How to add in Woocommerce checkout page a an extra fee checkbox

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, fee

In Woocommerce I would like to add a checkbox in checkout page that will add (charges) a fee if the user checks it a fee of 12.00. I have tried to use "[Add a custom checkbox in WooCommerce checkout which value shows in admin edit order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45905237/add-a-custom-checkbox-in-woocommerce-checkout-which-value-shows-in-admin-edit-or/45911284#45911284)" answer code for that.

Checkbox: Your shipping address is in a disadvantaged area?