# Display custom order meta data value in email notifications WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, email-notifications

Based on the following code

[Add a custom checkbox in WooCommerce checkout which value shows in admin edit order](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45911284/11987538)

I tried to add `my_field_name` to order confirmation email. As I understand I have to use `woocommerce_email_customer_details`.

So I came to this solution, unfortunately without the desired result.

```php
add_action('woocommerce_email_customer_details','woocommerce_email_order_invoice_number', 28, 4 );
function woocommerce_email_order_invoice_number( $order, $sent_to_admin, $plain_text, $email ) {
  if( $my_field_name = get_post_meta( $order->get_id(), 'my_field_name', true ) ) 
      echo '<p><strong>My custom field: </strong> <span style="color:red;">Is enabled</span></p>';
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have some minor mistakes, via the if condition `"$email->id == ..."`
you can target the mails

> **How to target other WooCommerce order emails**
>
> - 'customer_completed_order'
> - 'customer_processing_order'
> - 'customer_on_hold_order'
> - 'customer_refunded_order'
> - 'customer_reset_password'
> - 'customer_invoice'
> - 'customer_new_account'
> - 'customer_note'
> - 'cancelled_order'
> - 'failed_order'
> - 'new_order'

---

```php
function woocommerce_email_order_invoice_number( $order, $sent_to_admin, $plain_text, $email ) {
    // For 'new order'
    if ( $email->id == 'new_order' ) {
    
        // Get post meta
        $my_field_name = get_post_meta( $order->get_id(), 'my_field_name', true );
   
        // True and equal to     
        if ( $my_field_name && $my_field_name == 1 ) {
            echo '<p><strong>My custom field: </strong> <span style="color:red;">Is enabled</span></p>';
        }
    }
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_email_customer_details', 'woocommerce_email_order_invoice_number', 20, 4 );
```