# Append a measuring unit to the quantity field in WooCommerce email notifications

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, email-notifications

I'd like to append a unit to the quantity field in the order confirmation email, more precisely in the order items table of that email ([email-order-details.php](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/3611d4643791bad87a0d3e6e73e031bb80447417/plugins/woocommerce/templates/emails/email-order-details.php))

See screenshot:

[image]

---

I've tried to add this line of PHP

```php
`<?php echo '<p>VE</p>'; ?>`
```

into the HTML table in the template file, now my code looks like this:

```php
<div style="margin-bottom: 40px;">
<table class="td" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="6" style="width: 100%; font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Roboto, Arial, sans-serif;" border="1">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th class="td" scope="col" style="text-align:<?php echo esc_attr( $text_align ); ?>;"><?php esc_html_e( 'Product', 'woocommerce' ); ?></th>
            <th class="td" scope="col" style="text-align:<?php echo esc_attr( $text_align ); ?>;"><?php esc_html_e( 'Quantity', 'woocommerce' ); ?> <?php echo '<p>VE</p>'; ?></th>
            <th class="td" scope="col" style="text-align:<?php echo esc_attr( $text_align ); ?>;"><?php esc_html_e( 'Price', 'woocommerce' ); ?></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <?php
        echo wc_get_email_order_items( // phpcs:ignore WordPress.Security.EscapeOutput.OutputNotEscaped
            $order,
            array(
                'show_sku'      => $sent_to_admin,
                'show_image'    => false,
                'image_size'    => array( 32, 32 ),
                'plain_text'    => $plain_text,
                'sent_to_admin' => $sent_to_admin,
            )
        );
        ?>
    </tbody>
```

But my adjustment is not showing in the correct location. Can anyone help out with this and hint me in the right direction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need to edit/overwrite template files as you can just use the `woocommerce_email_order_item_quantity` filter hook

**So you get:**

```php
function filter_woocommerce_email_order_item_quantity( $qty_display, $item ) {
    $qty_display = $qty_display . ' VE';

    return $qty_display; 
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_email_order_item_quantity', 'filter_woocommerce_email_order_item_quantity', 10, 2 );
```

---

**Optional:** if you don't want to apply this to all e-mail notifications but target specific ones, you can use:

```php
// Setting the email_is as a global variable
function action_woocommerce_email_before_order_table( $order, $sent_to_admin, $plain_text, $email ) {           
    $GLOBALS['email_id_str'] = $email->id;
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_email_before_order_table', 'action_woocommerce_email_before_order_table', 10, 4 );
 
function filter_woocommerce_email_order_item_quantity( $qty_display, $item ) {
    // Getting the email ID global variable
    $refNameGlobalsVar = $GLOBALS;
    $email_id = isset( $refNameGlobalsVar['email_id_str'] ) ? $refNameGlobalsVar['email_id_str'] : '';

    // Targeting specific email. Multiple statuses can be added, separated by a comma
    if ( in_array( $email_id, array( 'new_order' ) ) ) {
        $qty_display = $qty_display . ' VE';
    }

    return $qty_display; 
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_email_order_item_quantity', 'filter_woocommerce_email_order_item_quantity', 10, 2 );
```

**Also see:** [How to target other WooCommerce order emails](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61459068/11987538)

---

Code goes in functions.php file of the active child theme (or active theme).