# How to remove white space above header in WooCommerce email notifications

Tags: css, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, email-notifications

I try  to remove white space above the header in WooCommerce email notifications.

I already pasted the email files into the folders:

> public_html -> wp-content -> themes -> flatsome-child -> woocommerce -> emails

I already tryed to hide the header with:

```php
/*do_action( 'woocommerce_email_header', $email_heading, $email );*/
```

But this is not solution because, yes it removes the white space above the header but also hides de header and I don't want this.

I just want to remove the empty space above the header (look the image attached)

[image: header-mail]

Answer (score 0):

The white space is applied via CSS. If you want to apply your own styles or want to modify the existing one in WooCommerce email notifications:

**1)** You can overwrite the template file:

- The template file can be overridden by copying it to `yourtheme/woocommerce/emails/email-styles.php`.

Replace line 50 - 56 @version 4.0.0

```css
#wrapper {
    background-color: <?php echo esc_attr( $bg ); ?>;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 70px 0;
    -webkit-text-size-adjust: none !important;
    width: 100%;
}
```

With

```css
#wrapper {
    background-color: <?php echo esc_attr( $bg ); ?>;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 70px 0;
    padding-top: 0;
    -webkit-text-size-adjust: none !important;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Also see: [Template structure & Overriding templates via a theme - How to Edit files](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/template-structure/#how-to-edit-files)

---

**OR**

**2)** Use the `woocommerce_email_styles` filter hook:

```php
// Add CSS to email
function filter_woocommerce_email_styles( $css, $email ) {
    $extra_css = '#wrapper { padding-top: 0 }';
    
    return $css . $extra_css;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_email_styles', 'filter_woocommerce_email_styles', 10, 2 );
```

Code goes in functions.php file of the active child theme (or active theme).

**Optional:** via `$email->id == ...` you can target specific emails, see [How to target other WooCommerce email notifications](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61459068/11987538)